# DotNetOpenAuth Implementation with ASP.net MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, openid, dotnetopenauth, oauth-2.0

I'm planning to use DotNetOpenAuth(http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) for implementing openid logging for my application.

Initially I facilitate Facebook, Google, Yahoo and Twitter open ids to log in to my web application.

Do I need to write consumers ie. google, facebook for each items or Are there any common implementations to handle that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could download the [OAuth2 CTP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/CTP/OAuth2/) which contains a sample project (`OAuthClient`) which has Facebook and Twitter implementations.

Comment: You only need OAuth2 for Facebook.  Twitter uses OAuth 1.0.  And Google and Yahoo both use OpenID.